# Python: Why is my program running when I insert pieces one by one, but not when all together?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

So I created this very easy paber-rock-scissors game in Python (Sorry, the strings are not in English).

Anyway, I am running it in IDLE and it works when I insert it like this:

1. from random import randint --> ENTER
2. Def my function --> ENTER
3. call my function --> ENTER

This way it runs as expected.

But when I put them all together and then press ENTER, it does nothing and when I call my function again, it says it's not defined.
Also, when I save it as .py and run it, it only pop's up for like 0.5 seconds.

My code is:

```
from random import randint
def myProgram():
    kpk = raw_input("Kivi, paber või kaarid?")
    random = randint(0,2)
    result = ""
    if kpk == "kivi":
        kpk = 0
        if random == 0:
            result = "VIIK"
        elif random == 1:
            result = "Kivi < Paber --- KAOTASID"
        else:
            result = "kivi > kaarid --- VOITSID"
    elif kpk == "paber":
        kpk = 1
        if random == 0:
            result = "kivi < paber --- VOITSID"
        elif random == 1:
            result = "VIIK"
        else:
            result = "paber < kaarid --- KAOTASID"
    elif kpk == "käärid":
        kpk = 2
        if random == 0:
            result = "kivi > kaarid --- KAOTASID"
        elif random == 1:
            result = "paber > kaarid --- VOITSID"
        else:
            result = "VIIK"
    else:
        print "Sisend peab olema uks kolmest: Kivi, paber või kaarid"
        myProgram()
    print result
    kas = raw_input("Kas soovite uuesti mangida? (Y/N)")
    if kas == "Y" or kas == "y" or kas == "jah":
        myProgram()
    else:
        print "Mang on läbi!"
myProgram()
```

Comment: All of this code doesn't seem relevant to your actual problem, could you maybe reduce it to something more minimal, that still exhibits the problem, perhaps defining a one-line function and then calling it.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I put them all together and then press ENTER"? Anyway if I run your program with `python kpk.py` it runs fine if i remove the non ASCII characters in your strings.

Comment: I tested your program and it runs fine. Meantime, your user will run into program, caused by your block

```else:
        print "Sisend peab olema uks kolmest: Kivi, paber või kaarid"
        myProgram()```

He will be forced to answer No multiple times, if he didn't put correct answer for ```Kivi, paber või kaarid```.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing this is the minimal version of your issue -

```
>>> def blah():
...     return 1
... blah()
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    blah()
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> blah()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'blah' is not defined
```

In the python shell/IDLE , you need to enter a newline (empty line) after a block has ended, so that python can interpret the block (this is valid for any blocks, like function definition, loops, `with` block, etc etc).

In the above, when I copied and pasted the code-

```
def blah():
    return 1
blah()
```

Without spaces, it would give the syntax errors , as there is not newline after the definition of function. One way (as you already observed) is to copy paste the function and function call separately (and make sure function gets defined by pressing enter/adding a newline at end) . (I am not sure if this is some kind of bug in the python shell, but it has been like that for both Python 2.x as well as Python 3.x ) .

Please note this is only when copy pasting code to the shell, not when saving your script as a .py file and running it , when running the code as a script, then newlines are not needed (though it would be better to put them for readability) .

Comment: this is just true if you type your code interactively in the python shell, but if you save it in a `.py` file the newline should not be needed.

Comment: @KlausPrinoth Yes, true , added that to the answer. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems like my code is okay. It runs perfectly fine when in IDLE I do RUN -> RUN MODULE

Although, RUN -> PYTHON SHELL does nothing.

Also, which program should I use to run my program. At the moment, when I save it as test.py and run it, a black window pops up for like 0.5 seconds and that's it. By default it's set to just "Python"

Comment: I tested your program from command-line by running ```python test.py```, where ```test.py``` stands for your program. Try to run command line prompt (via Win+R button -> "cmd" -> ENTER), to avoid closing the window.

Comment: Thank you! I am quite new to the command line but this worked very well!